# Posting to a form results in an AggregateException

Tags: c#, http-post, dotnet-httpclient

So I'm attempting to post a form using a HttpClient (and CloudFlareUtilities), and initialise it as shown below:

```
var handler = new ClearanceHandler {
    MaxRetries = 4,
};
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Connection.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = false;
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 " +
    "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36");
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
```

Creating the client is successful, with no apparent issues occurring. However, I create a POST request like below:

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("login", "username"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "pw"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("cookie_check", "1"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect", "myRedirect"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("register", "0"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("remember", "1")
});
```

and post the data:

```
var post = client.PostAsync("https://www.mc-market.org/login/login", content).Result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
```

The aforementioned line throws the error(s):

> Inner Exception 1:
>   HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream.
>
> Inner Exception 2:
>   IOException: The read operation failed, see inner exception.
>
> Inner Exception 3:
>   WinHttpException: The operation has been canceled

What I can interpret from this is that something went wrong, and something cancelled the task, yet I never cancel it myself.

Limiting errored line to

```
var post = client.PostAsync("https://www.mc-market.org/login/login", content);
```

gives the same error.

Is it possible I've created the Content incorrectly? Some indication of where I may have gone is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided not to go with the `HttpClient`, for simplicity.

Instead I opted to go with PhantomJS & Selenium, which natively supports Javascript in-browser anyway (which I decided to enable for the Cloudflare bypass).

What I then did is used its `SendKeys()` method to type in the login fields for in the website `https://www.mc-market.org/login/` (instead of `https://www.mc-market.org/login/login`), and press the button with `Click()`. An example is shown below;

```
driver.FindElementById("ctrl_pageLogin_login").SendKeys("NAME");
driver.FindElementById("ctrl_pageLogin_password").SendKeys("PASS");
driver.FindElementById("ctrl_pageLogin_remember").Click();
driver.FindElementByCssSelector("input.button.primary").Click();
```

The result was much simpler and it worked like a charm.